# Spring entity to DTO conversion

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have a class A like:

```
public class A{
    Long aa;
}
```

And a Jpa Repository been extended on it. Now `ARepo extends Jp...<A,Long>`

Now I have have another DTO B like:

```
public class B{
   Long bb;
   Long cc;
}
```

I use this DTO once in a while, that's why I don't directly save it in DB.

Now what I'm doing is:

```
List<A>as=aRepo.getAll();
List<B>bs=new ArrayList<>();
for(A a:as)
    bs.add(new B(a));
```

I don't like this and it seems real slow, how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try JPQL `NEW` operator:

```
public interface ARepo extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT NEW org.example.whatever.B(a) FROM A as a;")
    List<B> findAllAsBs();
    // all the other possible stuf...
}
```

You might need to adjust some aspects, but the principle.